# Java Eclipse - Error Message - Type Mismatch Can't convert from a void to a string

Tags: java

I am creating a game for my class. It will ask for you to guess a number between 1 and 100. I had to convert it from console to JOptionPane. When i tried, I got this error message. Keep in mind I am very new to Java.

Here is my  code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Randomm
{
   public static void frameGame()
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      int count = 0;
      int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
      String guess1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I am thinking of a number from 1 to 100"
            + " ... guess what it is ?");
      int guess = Integer.parseInt(guess1);
        count++;



      while (guess != a) {


          if (guess > a) {
              guess1 = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "lower!");
          } else if (guess < a) {
             guess1 = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "higher!");
          }
      }
      guess = Integer.parseInt(guess1);
      count++;


   }

   public static void main(String args[]) 
   {
      frameGame();
  }
}
```

There is the same error on both lines that say:

```
 guess1 = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null...
```

Thanks a lot!

Noah

Comment: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` != `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`: An input dialog queries some input from the user, a message dialog displays a message - hence, it returns `void` = *nothing*

Answer (score 2):

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` has no return value. So you cannot assign it to a variable.

Comment: The more helpful version of this answer is "You can't use this method to do what you want".  You need to find something that will prompt the user for input and then return that input to you.  The method you've chosen showMessageDialog does not do that.  If I knew how to solve your problem I'd make it an actual answer.  But I don't off hand and don't have time to research atm.  Sorry

Answer (score 1):

The showMessageDialog method returns void. So you can't assign the result of it to a variable (guess1)

Answer (score 0):

As has already been suggested in the comments, your problem is that `showMessageDialog(null, "whatever")` isn't going to return a String.

[Javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) shows the method you're calling is `void`, that is, it has no return value.

If you want to assign a String value as the result of showing the dialog, you need to call a method that will return a String, as you did above with `showInputDialog("whatever")`